# results of two feature selection algo do not match

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I am working on two feature selection algorithms for a real world problem where the sample size is 30 and feature size is 80. The first algorithm is wrapper forward feature selection using SVM classifier, the second is filter feature selection algorithm using Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient and Spearman's rank correlation coefficient. It turns out that the selected features by these two algorithms are not overlap at all. Is it reasonable? Does it mean I made mistakes in my implementation? Thank you.
FYI, I am using Libsvm + matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can definitely happen as both strategies do not have the same expression power.

Trust the wrapper if you want the best feature subset for prediction, trust the correlation if you want all features that are linked to the output/predicted variable. Those subsets can be quite different, especially if you have many redundant features.

Using top correlated features is a strategy which assumes that the relationships between the features and the output/predicted variable are linear, (or at least monotonous in case of Spearman's rank correlation), and that features are statistically independent one from another, and do not 'interact' with one another. Those assumptions are most often violated in real world problems.

Correlations, or other 'filters' such as mutual information, are better used either to filter out features, to decide which features not to consider, rather than to decide which features to consider. Filters are necessary when the initial feature count is very large (hundreds, thousands) to reduce the workload for a subsequent wrapper algorithm.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, but i am still confused that, taken Pearson correlation as an example, if one feature is highly correlated to the outputs (labels), using this feature in linear SVM the result should also be good since it will be easy to find linear boundaries between classes (there are 4 classes for my case). Or is it because SVM maximize the boundaries so that the data far away from boundaries are not important even they are highly correlated to the outputs? Maybe, I should use Linear Discriminant Analysis instead?

Comment: Indeed correlation and linear SVM do not solve the same optimization problem so the optimal solution to one is not the optimal solution to the other in theory. In practice, for 'easy' data, a feature with a high Pearson correlation coefficient with the label should be a good feature for a linear SVM. Except (1) if there are outliers (one single point can induce a correlation coefficient close to 1 if it is very distant from the others) and/or

Comment: (2) if there are multiple collinear features. It can also depend on the values of the [C parameter](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel) in the SVM. Make sure to optimize that one. Class imbalance can also affect the results. In the simple, two-Gaussian class problem, all methods (LDA included) will give the same results; on real-life, noisy, imbalanced, small sample, non-Gaussian, problems, they may give distinct results.

Comment: i choice the C value using grid search and cross validation. The value i choose has reached the highest accuracy of my training data. i think it may the imbalanced problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the distribution of the data you can either use spearman or pearson.The latter is used for normal distribution while former for non-normal.Find the distribution and use appropriate one.